# How to center multiple buttons in a ViewController?

Tags: xcode, autolayout, constraints

I have 3 buttons which I would like to center at the top of my ViewController, so that they remain centered regardless of the screen size of the iPhone or iPad. I have tried to:

- Use leading space and trailing space on the buttons either side of the view controller to center them.
- Put the buttons in a View and then center the view relative to the ViewController.
- Add the constraints as ratios.
- Use constraints on buttons.

None of these methods seem to work for me and I cannot figure out how to solve this. I have looked around for solutions but I cannot find anything that allows me to do this.

[image]

Comment: The method you are using can not guaranty the result you need. How did you set your constraints? Did you try `StackView`?

Comment: *None of these methods seem to work* isn't nearly enough description to let us help you. A more definite description of the desired result would also be helpful -- do you want the three buttons actually all to be centered, or have the middle one centered and the others some number of pixels away, or the same but have the others some percentage away?

Comment: @Caleb Sorry for being vague, I would like the buttons to be centred as a group, so the middle one centered and the other some percentage away ideally (so that it looks good on larger displays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> None of these methods seem to work for me and I cannot figure out how to solve this. I have looked around for solutions but I cannot find anything that allows me to do this.

It's easy to "center" the group of buttons using nothing but constraints. Here's an example:

[image: contstraints on 3 buttons]

To achieve this, I first constrained **Button 2** to the horizontal center of the safe area, and I constrained it's `top` to the safe area's `top` plus 128px. Then I constrained the `top` of **Button 1** and **Button 3** to be equal to the `top` of **Button 2**. Finally, I constrained the `trailing` of **Button 1** to the `leading` of **Button 2** plus 100px, and the `leading` of **Button 3** to the `trailing` of **Button 2** plus 100px. Here's how the constraints are listed:

[image]

I'm not sure why this isn't working for you -- you didn't give us any information about how your attempt failed. The other methods you listed should also work. For example, you can certainly put the buttons inside a view and center the view in the safe area or main view.

If you want the spacing to be proportional to the width of the screen, you can use the `multiplier` field of the constraints. For example, delete the horizontal spacing constraint between **Button 1** and **Button 2**, and then create a new one that constrains the `centerX` of **Button 1** to `centerX` of **Button 2**. Next, select the constraint that you just created and set it's `multiplier` field to, say, 0.5. You can do the same for **Button 3**, but set the `multiplier` to 1.5. Now you'll have **Button 2** centered in the safe area, and the other two buttons placed half way between the edge and center of the safe area, regardless of the screen dimensions. You can change the values to get different spacing, of course.